# Unmarshaling exception in parcelable object

Tags: android, fragment, parcelable, parcel

I have a problem with unmarshaling an parcelable object.
The exception is not reproducible every time but sometimes yes.
Here is the definition of the parcelable object :

```
public class Article extends DBOperationHolder implements Parcelable {

private static final String TAG = "Article_Object";

@SerializedName("article_id")
private int mId;

@SerializedName("city_id")
private int mCityId;

@SerializedName("categories")
private List<Integer> mCategories;

@SerializedName("neighborhood_tags")
private List<Integer> mNeighborhoodTags;

@SerializedName("cuisine_tags")
private List<Integer> mCuisineTags;

@SerializedName("collection_articles")
private List<Integer> mCollectionArticles;

@SerializedName("rating")
private int mRating;

@SerializedName("title")
private String mTitle;

@SerializedName("subtitle")
private String mSubTitle;

@SerializedName("summary")
private String mSummary;

@SerializedName("text")
private String mText;

@SerializedName("main_image_url")
private String mMainImgUrl;

@SerializedName("images")
private List<String> mImages;

@SerializedName("date_from")
private String mDateFrom;

@SerializedName("date_to")
private String mDateTo;

@SerializedName("venue_name")
private String mVenueName;

@SerializedName("address")
private String mAddress;

@SerializedName("address_latitude")
private double mAddressLatitude;

@SerializedName("address_longitude")
private double mAddressLongitude;

@SerializedName("contact_person")
private String mContactPerson;

@SerializedName("contact_email")
private String mContactEmail;

@SerializedName("contact_telephone")
private String mContactTelephone;

@SerializedName("contact_website")
private String mContactWebsite;

@SerializedName("style")
private String mStyle;

@SerializedName("ideal_for")
private String mIdealFor;

@SerializedName("favorite_tables")
private String mFavoriteTables;

@SerializedName("favorite_room")
private String mFavoriteRoom;

@SerializedName("signature_dishes")
private String mSignatureDishes;

@SerializedName("signature_drinks")
private String mSignatureDrinks;

@SerializedName("highlights")
private String mHighLights;

@SerializedName("type")
private String mType;

@SerializedName("membership_price")
private String mMemberShipPrice;

@SerializedName("membership_benefits")
private String mMemberShipBenefits;

@SerializedName("publish_date")
private String mPublishDate;

@SerializedName("article_url")
private String mArticleUrl;

private String mTag;
private boolean mIsCollection;
private int mIsAddedInFavorites;
private int mCategoryColor;
private String mCuisine;
private int mCategoryId;

public Article() {

}

public Article(int id) {
    mId = id;
}

private Article(Parcel in) {
    mId = in.readInt();
    mCityId = in.readInt();
    mRating = in.readInt();
    mTitle = in.readString();
    mSubTitle = in.readString();
    mSummary = in.readString();
    mText = in.readString();
    mMainImgUrl = in.readString();
    mDateFrom = in.readString();
    mDateTo = in.readString();
    mVenueName = in.readString();
    mAddress = in.readString();
    mAddressLatitude = in.readFloat();
    mAddressLongitude = in.readFloat();
    mContactPerson = in.readString();
    mContactEmail = in.readString();
    mContactTelephone = in.readString();
    mContactWebsite = in.readString();
    mStyle = in.readString();
    mIdealFor = in.readString();
    mFavoriteTables = in.readString();
    mFavoriteRoom = in.readString();
    mSignatureDishes = in.readString();
    mSignatureDrinks = in.readString();
    mHighLights = in.readString();
    mType = in.readString();
    mMemberShipPrice = in.readString();
    mMemberShipBenefits = in.readString();
    mPublishDate = in.readString();
    mIsAddedInFavorites = in.readInt();
    mTag = in.readString();
    mCategoryColor = in.readInt();
    mCuisine = in.readString();
    mCategoryId = in.readInt();
    mArticleUrl = in.readString();
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
    parcel.writeInt(mId);
    parcel.writeInt(mCityId);
    parcel.writeInt(mRating);
    parcel.writeString(mTitle);
    parcel.writeString(mSubTitle);
    parcel.writeString(mSummary);
    parcel.writeString(mText);
    parcel.writeString(mMainImgUrl);
    parcel.writeString(mDateFrom);
    parcel.writeString(mDateTo);
    parcel.writeString(mVenueName);
    parcel.writeString(mAddress);
    parcel.writeDouble(mAddressLatitude);
    parcel.writeDouble(mAddressLongitude);
    parcel.writeString(mContactPerson);
    parcel.writeString(mContactEmail);
    parcel.writeString(mContactTelephone);
    parcel.writeString(mContactWebsite);
    parcel.writeString(mStyle);
    parcel.writeString(mIdealFor);
    parcel.writeString(mFavoriteTables);
    parcel.writeString(mFavoriteRoom);
    parcel.writeString(mSignatureDishes);
    parcel.writeString(mSignatureDrinks);
    parcel.writeString(mHighLights);
    parcel.writeString(mType);
    parcel.writeString(mMemberShipPrice);
    parcel.writeString(mMemberShipBenefits);
    parcel.writeString(mPublishDate);
    parcel.writeInt(mIsAddedInFavorites);
    parcel.writeString(mTag);
    parcel.writeInt(mCategoryColor);
    parcel.writeString(mCuisine);
    parcel.writeInt(mCategoryId);
    parcel.writeString(mArticleUrl);
}


@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public static Creator<Article> CREATOR = new Creator<Article>() {
    @Override
    public Article createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new Article(source);
    }

    @Override
    public Article[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Article[size];
    }
};


public String getMainImgUrl() {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mMainImgUrl)) {
        if (!CollectionUtil.isEmpty(mImages)) {
            mMainImgUrl = mImages.get(0);
        }
    }
    return mMainImgUrl;
}

public int getId() {
    return mId;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    mId = id;
}

public int getCityId() {
    return mCityId;
}

public void setCityId(int cityId) {
    mCityId = cityId;
}

public List<Integer> getCategories() {
    return mCategories;
}

public void setCategories(List<Integer> categories) {
    mCategories = categories;
}

public List<Integer> getNeighborhoodTags() {
    return mNeighborhoodTags;
}

public void setNeighborhoodTags(List<Integer> neighborhoodTags) {
    mNeighborhoodTags = neighborhoodTags;
}

public List<Integer> getCuisineTags() {
    return mCuisineTags;
}

public void setCuisineTags(List<Integer> cuisineTags) {
    mCuisineTags = cuisineTags;
}

public List<Integer> getCollectionArticles() {
    return mCollectionArticles;
}

public void setCollectionArticles(List<Integer> collectionArticles) {
    mCollectionArticles = collectionArticles;
}

public int getRating() {
    return mRating;
}

public void setRating(int rating) {
    mRating = rating;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return mTitle;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    mTitle = title;
}

public String getSubTitle() {
    return mSubTitle;
}

public void setSubTitle(String subTitle) {
    mSubTitle = subTitle;
}

public String getSummary() {
    return mSummary;
}

public void setSummary(String summary) {
    mSummary = summary;
}

public String getText() {
    return mText;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    mText = text;
}

public void setMainImgUrl(String mainImgUrl) {
    mMainImgUrl = mainImgUrl;
}

public List<String> getImages() {
    return mImages;
}

public void setImages(List<String> images) {
    mImages = images;
}

public String getDateFrom() {
    return mDateFrom;
}

public void setDateFrom(String dateFrom) {
    mDateFrom = dateFrom;
}

public String getDateTo() {
    return mDateTo;
}

public void setDateTo(String dateTo) {
    mDateTo = dateTo;
}

public String getVenueName() {
    return mVenueName;
}

public void setVenueName(String venueName) {
    mVenueName = venueName;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return mAddress;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    mAddress = address;
}

public double getLatitude() {
    return mAddressLatitude;
}

public void setLatitude(double addressLatitude) {
    mAddressLatitude = addressLatitude;
}

public double getLongitude() {
    return mAddressLongitude;
}

public void setLongitude(double addressLongitude) {
    mAddressLongitude = addressLongitude;
}

public String getContactPerson() {
    return mContactPerson;
}

public void setContactPerson(String contactPerson) {
    mContactPerson = contactPerson;
}

public String getContactEmail() {
    return mContactEmail;
}

public void setContactEmail(String contactEmail) {
    mContactEmail = contactEmail;
}

public String getContactTelephone() {
    return mContactTelephone;
}

public void setContactTelephone(String contactTelephone) {
    mContactTelephone = contactTelephone;
}

public String getContactWebsite() {
    return mContactWebsite;
}

public void setContactWebsite(String contactWebsite) {
    mContactWebsite = contactWebsite;
}

public String getStyle() {
    return mStyle;
}

public void setStyle(String style) {
    mStyle = style;
}

public String getIdealFor() {
    return mIdealFor;
}

public void setIdealFor(String idealFor) {
    mIdealFor = idealFor;
}

public String getFavoriteTables() {
    return mFavoriteTables;
}

public void setFavoriteTables(String favoriteTables) {
    mFavoriteTables = favoriteTables;
}

public String getFavoriteRoom() {
    return mFavoriteRoom;
}

public void setFavoriteRoom(String favoriteRoom) {
    mFavoriteRoom = favoriteRoom;
}

public String getSignatureDishes() {
    return mSignatureDishes;
}

public void setSignatureDishes(String signatureDishes) {
    mSignatureDishes = signatureDishes;
}

public String getSignatureDrinks() {
    return mSignatureDrinks;
}

public void setSignatureDrinks(String signatureDrinks) {
    mSignatureDrinks = signatureDrinks;
}

public String getHighLights() {
    return mHighLights;
}

public void setHighLights(String highLights) {
    mHighLights = highLights;
}

public String getType() {
    return mType;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    mType = type;
}

public String getMemberShipPrice() {
    return mMemberShipPrice;
}

public void setMemberShipPrice(String memberShipPrice) {
    mMemberShipPrice = memberShipPrice;
}

public String getMemberShipBenefits() {
    return mMemberShipBenefits;
}

public void setMemberShipBenefits(String memberShipBenefits) {
    mMemberShipBenefits = memberShipBenefits;
}

public String getPublishDate() {
    return mPublishDate;
}

public void setPublishDate(String publishDate) {
    mPublishDate = publishDate;
}

public String getArticleUrl() {
    return mArticleUrl;
}

public void setArticleUrl(String articleUrl) {
    mArticleUrl = articleUrl;
}

public String getTag() {
    return mTag;
}

public void setTag(String tag) {
    UrbLog.d(TAG,"setTag("+tag+")");
    mTag = tag;
}

public boolean isCollection() {
   return mCategoryId == Category.COLLECTION_ID;
}

public int getIsAddedInFavorites() {
    return mIsAddedInFavorites;
}

public void setIsAddedInFavorites(int isAddedInFavorites) {
    mIsAddedInFavorites = isAddedInFavorites;
}

public int getCategoryColor() {
    return mCategoryColor;
}

public void setCategoryColor(int categoryColor) {
    mCategoryColor = categoryColor;
}

public String getCuisine() {
    return mCuisine;
}

public void setCuisine(String cuisine) {
    mCuisine = cuisine;
}

public int getCategoryId() {
    return mCategoryId;
}

public void setCategoryId(int categoryId) {
    mCategoryId = categoryId;
}
```

}

I`m trying to unmarshal the parcelable in the fragment's onCreate method here

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle args = getArguments();
    if (args != null) {
        mArticle = args.getParcelable(Consts.ARTICLE_KEY);
    }
}
```

Then not every time I received a crash with the following state:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@3348215c: Unmarshalling unknown type code 7602280 at offset 4068
   at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2222)
   at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2479)
   at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
   at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:804)
   at com.appscollider.urbanologie.fragments.ArticleFragment.onCreate(ArticleFragment.java:233)
   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1766)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:917)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1120)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:1924)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:268)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:58)
```

What is the reason for that exception and how I could fix it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `mAddressLatitude` and `mAddressLongitude` are of type double and you are unmarshalling them as type float:

```
mAddressLatitude = in.readFloat();
mAddressLongitude = in.readFloat();
```

If you are writing it as double it should be:

```
mAddressLatitude = in.readDouble();
mAddressLongitude = in.readDouble();
```

Comment: Okay, but in this case why that code work on some devices, I mean, sometimes the app crash, not EVERY time ?

Comment: That would be difficult to answer. But have you tried updating your unmarshalling code with the above changes and then check if it works on the devices the app crashed before?